# Create a dynamic menu in Umbraco 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu, umbraco

I am working on Umbraco and struggling to create dynamic menu in Umbraco.

The menu li's should be called using menuTitle.

The code I have currently is in partial views.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    <li>

    @foreach (var m in Model.Menu)
    {
      <li>
        <a href="@m.Url">@m.menuTitle</a>
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If Menu is a nodelist (like the MultiNodeTreePicker Data Type) you can use somethings like this:

```
var nodecommalist = CurrentPage.Menu.ToString().Split(',');
@foreach (var m in nodecommalist)
{
var mitem = Umbraco.Content(m);
<li>
    <a href="@mitem.Url">@mitem.menuTitle</a>
</li>
}
```

Or you could use somethings like this for showing all childs from the level 1 node:

```html
foreach (var m in CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1).Children.Where("hideInNavigation==False"))
{
  <li>
     <a href="@m.Url">@m.menuTitle</a>
  </li>
}
```

This Example use also a hideInNavigation it is a True/false Data Type.

Comment: Don't worry I have been able to fix this. Used one of the Umbraco tutorial videos as a guide. Thank you nayways.

Answer (score 0):

I Think following will do the trick.

```
@{
    @* Get the root of the website *@
    var root = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1);
}

<ul>
    @foreach (var page in root.Children.Where("Visible"))
    {
        <li class="@(page.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "current" : null)">
            <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

When rendering your site navigation, you don't run the query on the site every time a page is loaded. A good idea would be to do that query once to generate your dynamic menu as a model, and then store that model in the cache. That way when a page is loaded it just gets the model from memory and reduces the load on your website.

I wrote this blog post which gives you the code to be able to do what I said above.

http://www.codeshare.co.uk/blog/umbraco-site-navigation-menu-model-example-in-c-mvc/